# ElasticSearch Java API get only JSON Documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The Java API client normally returns a deserialized object, e.g.

```
SearchResponse<Product> result = client.search(searchRequest, Product.class);
```

For searches with many results e.g. 10000 documents, the process can have a high duration. Is it somehow possible to get only the raw source JSON as String to handle it by my own?

I tried already

```
SearchResponse<String> result = client.search(searchRequest, String.class);
```

but this leads to an MappingException.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SearchResponse<ObjectNode> result = client.search(searchRequest, ObjectNode.class);
```